# How to build a new app from scratch inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, development-environment

Docker is said to help isolate application environment, and help developers run the same environment. BUT all guides, tutorials, courses, etc start from an already built application. So how would i start a new application from scratch, let say in NodeJS?

So recently I've started to learn docker, and yes it is useful for packaging an already built application, if i already have everything installed in my local host machine and so on.

BUT how would I start developing a new application? For example in 
NodeJS, with no host installation of NodeJS, therefore I can't `npm init` my folder. How would I install new packages, how would the `node_modules` be persistent, and all that?

Here goes some very basis setup I used for packaging and app....THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME TO START FROM SCRATCH.

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  example-service:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm start
```

```
dev:
  docker-compose up
```

As seen in the code, i have a custom image, a docker-compose, and a makefile. I can change any piece of it or all of it. What I want is to develop my app with nothing installed in my host machine apart from docker, containers should isolate everything needed for the application, best practice to persist any new package installed during development.

Comment: Good question. I've only ever developed an app then copied it into the container. I'm curious if you could do all this from the command line, with some combination of VIM (would probably need to be installed separately), echo, etc. Or maybe you could install some sort of text editor like sublime or textwrangler?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow "[How to use Docker for Node.js development](https://cravencode.com/post/docker/nodejs-local-development/)" by [**Cody Craven**](https://cravencode.com/authors/cody-craven/):

It does use Docker itself to *develop*, not just deploy/run a NodeJS application.

Example:

```
# This will use the node:8.11.4-alpine image to run `npm init`
# with the current directory mounted into the container.
#
# Follow the prompts to create your package.json
docker run --init --rm -it -v "${PWD}:/src" -w /src node:8.11.4-alpine npm init
```

Then you can setup an execution environment with:

```
FROM node:8.11.4-alpine AS dev
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV NODE_ENV development
COPY . .
# You could use `yarn install` if you prefer.
RUN npm install
```

And build your app:

```
# Replace YOUR-NAMESPACE/YOUR-IMAGE with the name you would like to use.
docker build -t YOUR-NAMESPACE/YOUR-IMAGE:dev --target dev .
```

And run it:

```
# The `YOUR COMMAND` portion can be replaced with whatever command you
# would like to use in your container.
docker run --rm -it --init -v "${PWD}:/usr/src/app" YOUR-NAMESPACE/YOUR-IMAGE:dev YOUR COMMAND
```

All without node installed on your workstation!

Comment: Another approach, from 2016: https://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html, or (2017): https://github.com/shaunpersad/docker-tutorial

Comment: thanks but with that approach in development mode you'll spend more time building your image than developing your app, i've read and tried similar approches but when you are developing a large application you really waste a lot of time building the image everytime you add a module. Any other suggestion please

Comment: @alex The idea of this answer was to show you can use `npm` commands without installing node. If you don't want to use a container to compiling your project, don't. But the idea remains: through a `docker run` of a node image, you have access to node commands.

Comment: yes i get that, it is a really helpful idea, but is not my solution. I need to be able to develop inside a container my applicacion from scratch since i'm not able to install anything besides docker. So, any othe option??

Comment: @alex https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns0fHKuv7_Y, maybe? You can have a local cluster, with containers managed by a local Kubernetes, and as you can see in the video, full development, debugging and live deployment capabilities.